# Using MAMP's php instead of Mac OSX's php

Tags: php, macos, mamp

I added the path to MAMP's `php` and restarted terminal, but `which php` still points to the php that comes with Mac OSX.

**Question:** How can I switch to MAMP's php v5.4.10?

**Added to `.bash_profile` & `.bashrc`**

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php:$PATH
```

**`which php` after restarting Terminal**

```
/usr/bin/php
```

Answer (score 0):

Add only the *path* to your PATH, not the executable itself. Meaning only up to the `../bin` directory. The PATH is a list of *directories* in which executables are being looked for.

Comment: Works after adding to both! Do you add to `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`?